# CSS: why is list item shown without bullet?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list of items:

```
<ul>
    <li> item 1 </li>
    <li> item 2 </li>
</ul>
```

These are shown without the bullet. But why? Below are all the computed styles, copy-pasted from Chrome's Inspect element. What do I need to change? Display:list-item and list-style-type:disc seem to be ok.

(I am injecting html via javascript. That means that I can make my own style classes to override any styles that would otherwise be inherited, but I can't "remove" any styles from the parents.)

```
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
color: red;
display: list-item;
font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 17px;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: left;
width: 1389px;
```

Comment: I dont see anything in here that should be removing it. maybe try removing margin & padding for the left side...

Comment: Please provide a demo in which the issue is elaborated. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a nice way of sharing demos.

Comment: I just added an edit to the question: "I am injecting html via javascript. That means that I can make my own style classes to override any styles that would otherwise be inherited, but I can't "remove" any styles from the parents." It also means that I can't show a demo so easily. It's someone else's page with the injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They exist, they just are not visible. You broke the left border. Try

```
padding-left: 20px;
```

or

```
margin-left: 20px;
```

Comment: Cool, that did the trick (either or both, although padding-left:20px still cut off some of the number.) I am going to be inheriting unknown styles so I essentially need to reset everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give additional style that is `list-style-position:inside;` and check the [sample](http://jsbin.com/igeket/1/edit) code.

No need to change padding or margin.